# Multiple log files with SocketAppender

Tags: java, log4j, appender

I want to create mutiple log files using SocketAppender on the same server.

Server-Side properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] [%m]%n
```

Client-Side properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server
log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
log4j.appender.server.Port=4712
log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=divya
log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
```

I started the server using:

```
java -classpath log4j.jar org.apache.log4j.net.SimpleSocketServer 4712 log4j-server.properties
```

The above code creates log file 'logfile.log' on the server-side.
But, I want to create mutiple log files on the server-side with fileName as Transaction Ids. How do I do that?

Comment: You can use RollingPolicy.FileNamePattern to create multiple files with timestamp

Comment: I want to create log files with specific name i.e. Transaction Ids. How can I do that?(I should have specified this in the question)

Comment: you can create two different `RollingFileAppender` configurations for multiple files